# Dynamically loaded QML-file in Tab will only be executed when Tab is shown

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.3, qtquickcontrols

I'm creating `Tab`s in a `TabView` dynamically via

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("file://tabcontent.qml"));
tabView.addTab(component);
```

However their code is not executed before I click on the `Tab` itself.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The created [`Tab`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tab.html) inherits from [`Loader`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) with its `active` property set to `false` until the `Tab` is clicked. Just explicitly set the `active` property after creating it:

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("file://tabcontent.qml'));
var tab = tabView.addTab(component);
tab.active = true;
```